# grails removeFrom removes only one at a time

Tags: grails

I have a grails application where I have contacts which belongs to another domain contactGroup. It all seems to be working fine except for removeFromContacts method. I am using following code. The code works correctly but removes only one contact from the group at a time. I even did some debugging and the foreach loop runs as many times as the contacts provided. There is no error message. Any idea what could be going wrong -

```
    ContactGroup group = ContactGroup.findByIdAndOwner(params.groupId, user)

    def contactIds = request.JSON.data.contact
    contactIds.each {
        Contact contact = Contact.findByContactIdAndOwner(it.contactId, user)
        if(contact) {
            group.removeFromContacts(contact)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did u check whether the code in `if` loop is executing if there is some data in it?

Comment: I'm assuming that this is contained in a controller action that is supposed to remove all of the supplied `Contacts` from the given `ContactGroup`.  But your code is only removing one (presumably the first) each time the controller action is called.  If I understand the problem correctly I would add a `group.save(flush:true failOnError:true)` right after you remove each one from the group.

Comment: @JarredOlson You assumption is correct. It is in controller action and code is removing only first one. I dont think group.save is required or will make any difference. As per Grails doc, addTo and removeFrom methods donot require save method. They are automatically saved. Nevertheless I tried this also and the result was still same. Only first one is removed ...

Comment: @Ant's yes, I did check. the code is not only going into if loop everytime but it is getting correct contact for each loop (not just the first one). I had this as the first line in if(contact) loop -       println "remove contact with id" + contact.contactId + contact

Comment: Hibernate will pick up the change and automatically save the object, sometimes though that will hide your problem until it actually tries to flush the changes.  My suggestion was to see if there was an error occurring and it appears as if that is not the problem.  Kinda dumb question but are you certain the `Contacts` you're trying to remove are in fact associated with the given `ContactGroup`?  Maybe add a `println group.contacts.contains(contact)`.

Comment: @JarredOlson yes they are. I have a list method which displays all the ContactGroups and the contacts associated with them. There is no doubt in it because i can always see the first contact disappear from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your support. I realized that I have not defined the relationship at the domain level correctly and that was messing up with the whole thing. When I corrected that it was working correctly.

saurabh

Answer (score 0):

I've read a few things about the findAll methods loading proxies if the associations are lazy-loaded rather than the "real" instance.

Try this:

```
    group.removeFromContacts(Contact.get(contact.id))
```

The 'get' should bypass the proxies and use the "real" instance.  There is a JIRA that talks about this (Grails-5804).  An overall fix according to the JIRA (from Burt Beckwith) is to implement the equals and hashCode method in your Contact class.

Comment: I guess if this was an issue here, it will not work for only the first one and fail for others. Nevertheless I tried with this as well but the result was still the same.